# Return lowest level nodes (leafs) with topmost level nodes (roots)

Tags: sql, t-sql, common-table-expression

I would like to get all the leafs and their roots from a hierarchy table.
A leaf is the lowest level node and a root is the topmost level node.

Given a tree like:

```
A
--B
  --C
  --D
E
--F
--G
  --H
```

Leafs are nodes: `C`, `D`
Roots are: `A`, `E`

The table looks like (I've put parent names in parenthesis for clarity):

```
Id | Parent | Name
0  | NULL   | A
1  | 0 (A)  | B
2  | 1 (B)  | C
3  | 1 (B)  | D
4  | NULL   | E
5  | 4 (E)  | F
6  | 4 (E)  | G
7  | 6 (G)  | H
```

The result I'm looking for is:

```
Id | Parent | Name
2  | 0 (A)  | C
3  | 0 (A)  | D
5  | 4 (E)  | F
7  | 4 (E)  | H
```

I've already setup the following CTE query that is able to find all the roots for every leaf.

```sql
WITH Tree (Id, [Name], Parent) AS
(

      SELECT

            Id, [Name], Parent

      FROM

            dbo.Department

      WHERE 
           --Every leaf node, that is: a node that is never a parent
           Id IN (

            SELECT Id
            FROM Department
            WHERE Id NOT IN (
                SELECT Parent FROM Department
                WHERE Parent IS NOT NULL
            ))


      UNION ALL 

      SELECT

            dept.Id, dept.[Name], dept.Parent

      FROM

            dbo.Department dept

      INNER JOIN Tree ON 

            dept.Id = Tree.Parent

)
SELECT * FROM Tree
WHERE Parent IS NULL
```

But I have no idea how to add leafs id to the result along with its root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
WITH cte(id, name, root) AS
  (SELECT id, name, id FROM department WHERE parent IS NULL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT d.id, d.name, root
   FROM department AS d
   JOIN cte AS c ON d.parent = c.id)
SELECT id, root, name
FROM cte AS c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM department AS d WHERE c.id = d.parent)
ORDER BY id;
```

will give you all the leaves and their roots:

```
id          root        name      
----------  ----------  ----------
2           0           C         
3           0           D         
5           4           F         
7           4           H
```

[db<>fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4e06d5d1a582e814da9ee754cef1527f)

---

The trick is to have a column in the cte that starts out as the id of each root that's passed through unchanged to each child, grandchild, etc. in turn. Then just filter out the non-leaf rows.